# Python 3.6 How can I use ELSE or DEFAULT statement for xpath('@item').get() if the xpath does not exist

Tags: python, xpath

Hi we loop over some cells and get the values using `xpath('@item').get()`

In the almost all cells have `@item` for the cells that do not have this value set (at all) a warning is raised

This is our code:
`item['qty'] = model_cell.xpath('@data-stock').get()`

Error is:
`WARNING: Invalid qty (None) at https://example.com`

**question**: how can we make this smarter with some if/else logic like a Ternary Operator.

Logic: Try get `xpath('@data-stock').get()` if it does not exist, return value 0

(or return some default value if not found)

Data example (get all data-stock values)

```
<td id=1 data-stock="13"></td>
<td id=2 ></td>
<td id=3 data-stock="11"></td>
```

problem occurs @ id=2 td

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "does not exist"? What does it return then?

Comment: the xpath does not exist .. so it is not found and nothing can be get()

Comment: So `model_cell.xpath('@data-stock')` returns `None` in that situation?

Comment: WARNING: Invalid qty (None) at https://urlhere

Comment: Would `try:
    item['qty'] = model_cell.xpath('@data-stock').get()
except KeyError:
    item['qty'] = 0` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `model_cell` is the `td` element and `xpath()` is from lxml...

You shouldn’t need to use xpath to get the attribute value; you can just use `get()` with a default value.

```
item['qty'] = model_cell.get('data-stock', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_elements_by_xpath` and get all elements of td tag then traverse the loop and check the attribute `data-stock` if None print something else print attribute value.

```
 elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('..//td')

    for element in elements:
        if element.get_attribute("data-stock") is None:
            print("no item")
        else:
            print(element.get_attribute("data-stock"))
```